# How to download a big area OSM by JOSM editor

Tags: openstreetmap, josm

I download a small rectangle of data osm using JOSM, but when trying to download a big area the message error shows that the server will not allow it.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OSM API doesn't allow to download areas greater than few sq km. Try to use downloading using overpassAPI - it's in File menu, but this also doesn't allow you to download all planet. Keep in mind that more data = less performance in JOSM.

Answer (score 3):

Try some download sources listed at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm and make use of tools like "osmconvert" and "osmfilter" (see OSM-Wiki) to get raw OSM data for bigger areas.

Comment: I think that there is an extension on JOSM enable downloading big area by spliting it to small rectangles

Answer (score 3):

The main API is essentially an *editing* API only. It should not be used to perform bulk downloads.

See the [country and area extracts](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts). If they are still too large for you then see [OSM file formats](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_file_formats) which has some notes about processing these files and splitting them into different geographical regions, e.g. by using [osmium](http://osmcode.org/osmium-tool).